# OpenCV: Multiply Images in C++ and C

Tags: c++, c, opencv, matrix-multiplication

I've just used the multiply functions using C api (cvMul) and C++ api (mul and multiply). But I get a different result from the C function and the C++ ones

- [Result of cvMul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NieG.jpg) (it is a white image)
- [Result of mul and multiply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArvjH.jpg)

Here is the code I use for both implementations:

C

```
IplImage * gh = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(input),IPL_DEPTH_32F,1) ;
cvSobel(input,gh,1,0) ;

IplImage * gh2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(input),IPL_DEPTH_32F,1) ;
cvMul(gh,gh,gh2) ;
```

C++

```
Mat gh = Mat (input.size(), CV_32FC1);
Sobel(input, gh, CV_32FC1, 1, 0);

Mat gh2 = Mat (input.size(), CV_32FC1);
gh2 = gh.mul(gh); // multiply (gh, gh, gh2);
```

The input image is the same, and when I check the horizontal gradient it is also the same for both implementations, so why would the multiplication give different results? (I am interested in getting the result of the C implementation)

Comment: That's odd because, at least in OpenCV 3.0, the code for `cvMul` converts the arrays to `Mat`s and calls `multiply`. Are you sure the difference isn't in the Sobel filter?

Comment: check that the out put of both image in the same range for example 0..255 otherwise you should normalize them

Comment: @beaker I did check the results of the Sobel filter and they looked to be the same, I even substracted both Images (the c sobel result and the c++) to see if there were some "unnoticeable" differences but there none...

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Can I do this checking by getting the min and max values of each Mat? If not do you know how can I do it?